# h264_omx and non-existing PPS 0 referenced

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

Trying to stream a webcam through rtp with a raspberry pi.

Cating the SDP file on my desktop, and launching ffplay:

```
ffplay sdp.out
```

then streaming out this way:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.101:1234
```

works perfectly. But If I launch ffmpeg first THEN ffplay, ffplay stutters some error message about missing PPS and never displays any frame:

```
[h264 @ 0x7fd97c0008c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fd97c0008c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fd97c0008c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
```

After looking for a while I understand some intermediary frame might be missing. However, using the `-g` option this way does not change anything:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -g 30 -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.101:1234
```

It is a problem for me because I am using the raspberry as a securiy camera. My desktop can be restarted from time to time and I need ffplay to be able to catch after the streaming is started.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rather than a intermediary frame being missing, it's about head frames. When ffplay starts, if the first frame it receives is not a keyframe, then that frame needs a previous (missing) frame to get decoded. That previous frame may be a I-frame not queued to be ever shown or a P frame referred to by a B-frame and would have been shown after the B-frame had it been received.

Comment: I'm confused. Does it mean there is no solution to this problem (it's the way rdp works, the listener has to be started and then the flow started) or there would be a way to regularly insert  a keyframe for the listener to be able to catch the stream in the middle.

Comment: Does the stream not become smooth after a few seconds?

Comment: No, ffplay keeps outputing error message for ever. It is never able to display any frame.

Comment: Does replacing `-g 30` with `-force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced)"` work?

Comment: Indeed, thanks to your suggestion I found another interesting question about this: http://superuser.com/questions/908280/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-keyframes-in-ffmpeg-for-dash. So I'll try `force_key_frames` and also check the result with the forensic method mentioned in the question and let you know.

Comment: I tried your solution to no avail. ffplay is still not able to display anything if not started first. If I dump the output into a file, I see that intermediate frames are generated:`./ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264_omx -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced)' -o file.avi`
and then `./ffprobe -i file.avi -select_streams v -show_frames -of csv -show_entries frame=pict_type`. O see some `frame,I` in the middle of the `frame,P`. So why would ffplay not able to decode those frame? Is this a limitation of the rdp protocol somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is impossible to live stream with the RPi hardware acceleration using ffmpeg.
For ffmpeg to configure the hardware acceleration to issue SPS/PPS frames during the stream and not only at the beginning of it, it needs to use a [specific API of the raspberry firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/242) which it does not at the moment.

[Raspivid](http://frozen.ca/streaming-raw-h-264-from-a-raspberry-pi/) and [gstreamer](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/omxh264enc-and-stream-format-string-avc-td4671543.html) does that though. So turn to thoses solution and forget about ffmpeg.

Comment: If this is the issue, then you may be able to stream the omx encode to a pipe in mpegts format and then use a 2nd ffmpeg instance to pipe to rtp. The MPEG-TS muxer will insert xPS in-band.

Answer (score 0):

Here my FFmpeg patch to enable inline header on OMX hardware encoder.

libavcodec/omx.c
OMX_SetParameter(s->handle, OMX_IndexParamBrcmVideoAVCInlineHeaderEnable, &vid_param_inline_header);
where vid_param_inline_header is a OMX_CONFIG_PORTBOOLEANTYPE struct.

https://github.com/Serveurperso/FFmpeg/commit/6e410823e63103342e8fc3407ff6698808d4d1ef

Comment: Consider submitting a patch to ffmpeg-devel but make it an option instead of hardcoded.

Comment: Yes but there is a last problem:( only when I enable OMX InlineHeader the latency grow over the time.There is a strange time calculation problem inside the muxer. I get a lot of "application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream xxxx/0" and it always freeze at 3335.